# Run code when Signal is sent, but do not trap the signal in Ruby

Tags: ruby, signals

I have code that is running on a server, before the server is hard shut down, a signal `SIGTERM` is sent to let my code know it needs to clean up. I want to run code when this happens and send the signal back to the same program so any other code that needs to clean up can do so. I do not want to trap the signal or change signal behavior, I only need to run something before the rest of my program interprets the SIGTERM.

Currently I can do something like

```
Signal.trap('TERM') do
  puts "Graceful shutdown"
  exit
end
```

but it doesn't work if multiple pieces of code in the same app try to do the same thing. For example:

```
Signal.trap('TERM') do
  puts "Graceful shutdown"
  exit
end

Signal.trap('TERM') do
  puts "Another graceful shutdown"
  exit
end
```

You will only ever see `"Another graceful shutdown"` and the first code block will not run.

Ideally I would be able to invoke current behavior with something like:

```
Signal.trap('TERM') do
  puts "another graceful shutdown"
  super
end
```

But this doesn't work for obvious reasons. So the question is this: how can I run code when i get a `SIGTERM` without trapping it and preventing other code from doing the same?

Comment: It looks like I can do this with threads https://gist.github.com/schneems/fb1e27f5847cfc2ba5f4 but i'm not sure if that's the best way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Signal.trap` returns the previous handler so you can do something like

```
def prepend_handler(signal, &handler)
  previous = Signal.trap(signal) do
    previous = -> { raise SignalException, signal} unless previous.respond_to?(:call)
    handler.call(previous)
  end
end

prepend_handler("TERM") do |old|
  do_something
  old.call
end
```

The `respond_to?` business is because a handler is either a callable or a string (the string values are documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Signal.html)). Unless you use those string handlers yourself you are most likely to run into 'DEFAULT', i.e. the default ruby behaviour

Comment: dpiddy had a good idea to call `raise SignalException, "TERM"` to invoke the original behavior. We could use that instead of exit.

Comment: We could also wrap that logic into the `prepend_handler`. Something like this https://gist.github.com/schneems/41a30bd72153c6782746

Comment: Yes, that's much nicer @Schneems

Comment: Suppose the previous handler was IGNORE, DEFAULT, EXIT or SYSTEM_DEFAULT. After our custom handler is executed, will the code that would have been executed if we had not installed our handler, be still executed?

Comment: @Dan Unless you re-raise I don't believe the default behaviour will be triggered (but do try this out!)